# How to reduce space between table and image locally?

Tags: tables

How to reduce a space under a table and above an image only in one case, not in all document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\small
\cetering
\caption[]{Caption}\label{jou}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A & A \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
\caption{Photometric data displayed with respect to time}
\label{rozlozeni}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are adding space with `center` in floats (which add space already) it is better to use `\centering` not the center environment,

Comment: In addition to the previous comment: What is the purpose of the `\centerline` command in the `figure` environment? There is no need to center an image that is as wide as the textwidth.

Comment: Thank you, I eddited it, however, there is still huge space (I added a picture to my question).

Comment: the space depends on code you have not shown but if you really want to just change that one space put a blank line and `\vspace{-20pt}` (or whatever you need) before `\end{table}`

Comment: Great, thank you very much